# How can I loop a music so it doesnt stop playing in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make a game with pygame and I want to loop a music but when I put it in my main loop it just repeats the first second.

```
import pygame
import os
from pygame import mixer

pygame.init()
mixer.init()

#here i have all the display settings and stuff so im not gonna write them

mixer.music.load(os.path.join("Music", "music.wav"))
mixer.music.play()
```

I want this to play in a loop without stopping but I don't know how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from the documentation for pygame.mixer.play:

> The loops argument controls the number of repeats a music will play. play(5) will cause the music to played once, then repeated five times, for a total of six. If the loops is -1 then the music will repeat indefinitely.

so call

```
mixer.music.play(loops=-1)
```

Comment: @ErenBiçer: if it works as expected you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)